# Raising awareness about a Fourier analysis issue

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have just posted a query on Wolfram's own forum: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2299913?p_p_auth=HBTdYN1c
This is because it allows me to share the notebook I am working on and therefore hopefully means that I will get more specific advice. Would you mind terribly if I also post it on here just to raise awareness amongst the community in case anyone can help? Sorry if this is not how it works - happy to learn and amend! Best wishes.

Comment: Your code from that Wolfram Community post is certainly short enough to post here (although you don't want to include some of the intermediate output - just end such output producing statements with a semicolon).  But your 3 questions are really 3 separate questions.  Asking each one separately with a minimal working example is just fine.

Comment: This can be reopened if you can edit the question to be self-contained (altho you should still include the Community link as a cross-reference).

Comment: @J.M.'storpor - I don't know how to do that. Please could you just open it again?

Comment: Just click the ‘Edit’ button and then you change the content.